# Adding cost to a ListBox

Tags: c#, class, listbox

I currently have a listbox that displays the date, type of cake and size. I want to add cost to the listbox, but I am having trouble. It currently displays zero for the cost. The cost is displayed in a label (lblRoundCost). I have a base class named Cake and two subclasses RoundCake and SquareCake. I'm not sure if this code is correct for the base class:

```
class Cake
{

    private const int CostOfFoodPerPerson = 25;
    public int size;
    private bool chocolateIcing; 
    protected DateTime cakeDate;
    decimal cost;

public Cake(int numberOfPeople, bool chocolateIcing, DateTime cakeDate)
{

    this.chocolateIcing = chocolateIcing;   
    Size = size;    
    this.cakeDate = cakeDate;
    Cost = cost;
}

public virtual decimal Cost
{
    get { return cost; }
    set { cost = value; }
}

public virtual int Size
{
    get { return size; } 
    set { size = value; }
}

public virtual bool ChocolateIcing
{
    set { chocolateIcing = value; }
}

public virtual decimal CalculateCost()
{
    decimal CostOfIcing = 0; 
    if (chocolateIcing)
    CostOfIcing = (Size * 1.5M) + 10M;

else

    CostOfIcing = 0; 
    decimal TotalCost = CostOfIcing + CostOfFoodPerPerson;
    return TotalCost;
}

public DateTime CakeDate
{
    set { cakeDate = value; }
}

}
}
```

RoundCake code

```
class RoundCake : Cake
{

bool fruitOption;

public RoundCake(int size, bool fruitOption, bool chocolateIcing, DateTime cakeDate)

: base(size, chocolateIcing, cakeDate)

{FruitOption = fruitOption;}

public bool FruitOption

{ 
    set { fruitOption = value; }
}


public override decimal CalculateCost()
{

decimal totalCost;

if (fruitOption)

{

totalCost = base.CalculateCost(); 
return totalCost + (totalCost * .05M);
}

else 

{

totalCost = base.CalculateCost() ; 
return totalCost;
}
}

public override string ToString()
{

    return String.Format("{0,-20}{1,2}{2,20}{2,20}", cakeDate.ToShortDateString(), "RC",Size,Cost);
}
```

Form1 code

```
private void btnRound_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    lstCake.Items.Add(roundCake);
}

roundCake = new RoundCake((int)nudRound.Value, chbFruit.Checked, chbChocoRound.Checked,
dtpRound.Value.Date);
lblRoundCost.Text = roundCake.CalculateCost().ToString("c");
```

Comment: Your posted code looks incomplete and uncompilable to boot.  You have fields declared outside of classes and assignments outside of methods.

Comment: @Tim The full code is too long to post. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post everything.

Comment: Post enough to show what you're trying to do, you don't need to post everything (and you shouldn't) - but posting a mish-mash of code doesn't do you any good either and people will have a harder time trying to help you.   Post the base class, the `RoundCake` class and an example of how you're instantiating an instance of `RoundCake` as a starter and let's see if we can figure out the issue.

Comment: @Tim I added the base class and subclass. I'm still completely confused on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Pay attention to your `ToString()` implementation. Should be `{0,-20}{1,2}{2,20}{3,20}`

Comment: @kennyzx Now the cost shows up as zero instead of the size value. I think I have to set the Cost equal to the label (lblRoundCost) somehow. Thank you though.

Comment: Missing one piece of information - how does all of this tie into the `ListBox`?  In other words, are you expecting cost to show up in the `.ToString()` method?  It looks like it should based on your code.

Comment: @Tim When I click on the button (btnRound) everything shows up correct in the listbox, except the cost is always zero. Yes, I am expecting cost to show up in the .ToString() method.

Comment: @Strongbad2143 - I think I know what's going on....answer to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing 0 is because you never actually assign anything to `Cost`, and the default for `decimal` is 0.

Here's what's happening:

In your base constructor, you have:

```
Cost = cost;
```

However, `cost` is never initialized in the class and it's not passed in via the constructor.  So in the base it's 0.

The same thing happens with the inheriting class - `Cost` is never specified, so it's still going to be 0 (even if there wasn't a base class, it'd still be 0).

Now, in this line of code:

```
lblRoundCost.Text = roundCake.CalculateCost().ToString("c");
```

You're assigning the value calculated by `CalculateCost()` to the `Label`, but you're never persisting that value in the the class:

```
public override decimal CalculateCost()
{

    decimal totalCost;

    if (fruitOption)
    {
        totalCost = base.CalculateCost(); 
        return totalCost + (totalCost * .05M);
    }
    else 
    {
        totalCost = base.CalculateCost() ; 
        return totalCost;
    }
}
```

You're *returning* a value, but not assigning it to the class member `cost`.  The base implementation does the same thing.

There a number of ways to solve this.  Here's one (this is a pretty simple one, and to be honest it has a bit of a code smell to me, but it'll server as an example):

Modify the `CalculateCost()` method to update the `cost` field:

```
public virtual void CalculateCost()
{

    decimal CostOfIcing = 0; 

    if (chocolateIcing)
        CostOfIcing = (Size * 1.5M) + 10M;
    else
        CostOfIcing = 0; 

    decimal cost = CostOfIcing + CostOfFoodPerPerson;
}
```

Note that this doesn't return a type anymore (you may have it still do so, it really depends a lot on your overall design, so pick the path that works best for your design).  Don't forget to make this change in the inheriting class's implementation as well.

Now you simply need to call the `CalculateCost()` method and you will have the cost available, and you can use the property to get the cost for assignment to `Labels` or whatever else you need, and it will show up in your overridden `ToString()` method.

Again, there are multiple ways to solve this, and they depend on a mix of OOP principles and your design needs.  My main intention with this answer was to demonstrate why `cost` was showing up as zero.

Comment: I had to add return cost otherwise I get an error. I changed the totalCost to cost and it worked. Your answer made a lot of sense. I appreciate the help. Thank you.